# I Have a notification in the status bar code, but AIDE is marking two things as wrong

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to make a Status Bar Notification and I got this code from research, but it doesn't seem to be working out when I placed the code into `MainActivity.java` with AIDE

```
NotificationManager
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
getSytemService(Context.N);
Notification notification = new notification(R.drawble.ic_launcher,
"Notification Test", System.currentT;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification Title";
CharSequence contentText ="This is the message";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

The errors seem to be at `Line 3` with the `(Context.N)` where the `N` has the error message: `Unknown member 'N' of 'android.content.Context'`. The other error message is on the fifth line where it reads `System.currentT` with the error message of `Unknown member 'currentT' of 'java.lang.Sytem'`.

Answer (score 0):

`Context.N` should be [`Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#NOTIFICATION_SERVICE).

`System.currentT` should be [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

It seems that you are copying the code from somewhere but got the code truncated?

---

Here's a sample method for generating notifications.

<sup>*This is based on Android's doc: [Building a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html). For more details (e.g. how to display a progress bar or an extended view), please read the docs.*</sup>

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String messageTitle, String messageText)
{
    // Get notification manager.
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Setup notification builder.
    final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
        .setContentText(messageText)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    // Create intent.
    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // Setup task stack builder.
    final TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    // Create pending intent.
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Update notification builder.
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Post notification.
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) class requires Android's version 4 [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html).

Comment: I'll accept the answer when I can it says I have to wait 9 minutes

Comment: Is your code complete? You also need some more code (e.g. `notificationManager.notify()` to show a notification).

Comment: Hmm that was all the code I thought was there when I did my research let me check again

Comment: that's all the code I can find from this source what's the rest that I need to add

Comment: Try `mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);`. If that doesn't work, I'd recommend you to use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` class instead. For a tutorial, see Android's doc: [Building a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Comment: So far AIDE isn't marking the code wrong see how the build works out now

Comment: the first one crashed when the activity opened so I tried the second one and it isn't working either I'll try the second link

Comment: It is advised to use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` class to build a `Notification` for best compatibility support across all versions of Android platform. The code on Android's docs work for me so it should work for you too. Good luck.

Comment: I even tried the link you sent are you sure this code works for Android 2.3.4?

Comment: the final line says `mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationID, builder.build());` but the response from AIDE is marked wrong as `Unknown entity 'builder'`

Comment: You missed [the first part which creates the builder](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#builder) (or rename `mBuilder` to `builder`).

Comment: Okay sorry I removed all my previous code and inserted the 1st and last code on the link provided